# Chrome Tab Sync javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a javascript API for Chrome Tab Sync for web sites? I'm not asking about Chrome Extensions, just web sites.

For example, I'd like to store some text (a string) when you open a web site on the desktop then when you open that same page in the chrome mobile browser I'd like to display that stored text.

Is this possible? I know with Chrome Extensions there is chrome.storage, but I don't believe that is available for websites.

Comment: It's probably better to keep track of this sort of thing on your own servers anyway.  Who knows what Google might change.

Comment: I'm more curious on how to accomplish this using Tab Sync. What I'm building is specific to Chrome. The game at chrome.com/maze allows users to connect their desktop and mobile Chrome through tab sync without the need of a special url. They must be able to access some sort of shared storage based on signed in Chrome user to make this connection/sync. That is what I'm interested in learning about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store that information:

- on your server,
- in the URL of the page (`?mystring=...`),
- or on your server with a lookup key for the specific info in the URL.

Any one of these is an ordinary thing to do and will work for all browsers and all ways to get a page from one device to another, without relying on any features specific to Chrome.